# What is the lift coefficient of the B767-400ER?

Tags: aircraft-performance, boeing-767

Can anyone tell me what is the lift coefficient of B767-400ER please? I have searched it in Boeing website and Delta Airlines website but still couldn't find the data of the aircraft performances. Where could I find the detailed specifications of the aircraft?

Comment: Which lift coefficient are you looking for? Maximum? In cruise? At take-off rotation? Since the 767 can have very different weights and fly at very different speeds, the lift coefficient will also vary.

Comment: Similar question: [How to calculate the Lift Coefficient for the A320?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14538/how-to-calculate-the-lift-coefficient-for-the-a320) Going into more detail about what coefficient of lift means [How do we derive Lift Coefficient of an airplane's wing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/58304/how-do-we-derive-lift-coefficient-of-an-airplanes-wing)

Comment: There's an article on drag polar estimation for high subsonic aircraft [on this link](https://www.sesarju.eu/sites/default/files/documents/sid/2018/papers/SIDs_2018_paper_75.pdf)